# Conque-GDB in vim: how to set size

Tags: vim, gdb, plugin

I use Conque-GDB as a plugin in Vim.

Here is how my Vim now looks like:
[image]

As you see I also use the Nerdtree and I can easily change its size:
https://codeyarns.com/2014/05/08/how-to-change-size-of-nerdtree-window/

But I don't know how to change the size of Conque-GDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ConqueGDB is a split in vim, so you can always resize it using vim commands, for example:

```
:resize +20
:res -20
```

Where `+20` and `-20` is the number of pixels that will be added or subtracted from the current split size.

The same way you can increase/decrease the sizing of the NERDTree:

```
:vertical resize +20
```

Not sure if there is any way to specify the default split size for the ConqueGDB on its start, but you can always map the above commands for quicker resizing after the ConqueGDB is launched.

More on [how to resize vim splits more quick](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Resize_splits_more_quickly).

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with modifying the source code, there is a definition for the `:ConqueGdb` command in `plugin/conque_gdb.vim`:

```
" Commands to open conque gdb
command! -nargs=* -complete=file ConqueGdb call conque_gdb#open(<q-args>, [
        \ get(g:conque_gdb_src_splits, g:ConqueGdb_SrcSplit, g:conque_gdb_default_split),
        \ 'buffer ' . bufnr("%"),
        \ 'wincmd w',
        \ 'res -15'])
```

As you can see, I've just added `res -15` at the very end and it seems to do the trick.
Additionally, if you want to preserve that sizing when you later re-open the split, you have to invoke the same command in the `conque_gdb#command` function definition found in `autoload/conque_gdb.vim`:

```
" Send a command to the gdb subprocess.
function! conque_gdb#command(cmd)
    if !(bufloaded(s:gdb.buffer_number) && s:gdb.active)
        echohl WarningMsg | echomsg "GDB is not running" | echohl None
        return
    endif

    if bufwinnr(s:gdb.buffer_number) == -1
        let s:src_buf = bufnr("%")
        let s:src_bufwin = winnr()
        sil exe 'noautocmd ' . get(g:conque_gdb_src_splits, g:ConqueGdb_SrcSplit, g:conque_gdb_default_split)
        sil exe 'noautocmd wincmd w'
        sil exe 'noautocmd buffer ' . s:gdb.buffer_number
        " CUSTOMIZATION: Always resize the split a little
        sil exe 'res -15'
        sil exe 'noautocmd wincmd p'
    endif
"...
endfunction
```

Hacky, but it works so I don't care much.